# C# get and set, shorthand and access control

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    class Ad
    {
        public string _name { private get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Ad ad = new Ad();
        Console.WriteLine(ad._name = "Name");
    }

}
```

Code output : "Name" , but _name field's get is private. Why I don't get an error?

Comment: Why would you? You're not calling the getter - you're calling the setter.

Comment: Your code as you posted it isn't valid. The `Ad` class has no `_adi` property.

Comment: @JonSkeet true, but isn't the `Console.WriteLine` immediately turning around and reading the `_adi` property (I assume that should actually be `_name`) after it's being set?

Comment: @RussellUhl: Nope. The result of `ad._adi = "Name"` is "the value assigned to the property" without any extra getter access.

Comment: @JonSkeet Gotcha.  Good to know!

Comment: Console.WriteLine(ad._name); will generate a compile error.

Comment: OP, your code doesn't compile. It's easiest to help you when you post the actual code you're working with.

Comment: *The result of a simple assignment expression is the value assigned to the left operand. The result has the same type as the left operand and is always classified as a value.* [C# Language Specification: 7.13.1 Simple assignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691315.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why I don't get an error?

Because you're writing the *result of the assignment*. The code `string result = ad._name = "Name"` will store the result of `ad._name = "Name"` in the `result` variable, which is "Name".

So you're not calling the getter, like [@Jon addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26428456/c-sharp-get-and-set-shorthand-and-access-control/26428764#comment41501920_26428456).

See [7.13.1 Simple assignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691315(v=vs.71).aspx):

> The result of a simple assignment expression is **the value assigned to the left operand**. The result has the same type as the left operand and is always classified as a value.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of know what you're trying to do. I guess your code is like this:

```
    class Program
{
    class Ad
    {

        public string _name { private get; set; }


    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Ad ad = new Ad();
        Console.WriteLine(ad._name = "Name");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Of course it will work, since you're not actually calling the get of ad._name.

Try this and you'll see:

```
    class Program
{
    class Ad
    {

        public string _name { private get; set; }


    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Ad ad = new Ad();
        ad._name = "Name";
        Console.WriteLine(ad._name);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

You'll get the following error: "Error  1   The property or indexer 'ConsoleApplication7.Program.Ad._name' cannot be used in this context because the get accessor is inaccessible  ... "